# What is the meaning of this Title: "Home sweat home" not "sweet"

Tags: reading-comprehension

**Home sweat home**

Once I read one small article called *Home sweat home* and I didn't understand why this is called in this way.

In this article the main thing is *Climate change* and its "supporters", namely 2 men who had a lot of struggles which they come across while raising people's awareness to *climate change* that, of course, effects the whole planet.

And, can you give information about why this article is named in this way.

Comment: Without knowing the author's mind, and without access to the article, I can only guess that it's a play on words about how global warming increases temperatures and makes people sweat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a pun, a joke exploiting the fact that the words "sweet" and "sweat" sound alike.  It is about how global warming would increase the temperature of *our home, the Earth*, and make us sweat. It will change our home from "sweet" to "sweaty".

It is fairly common to use puns and other forms of wordplay in headlines.  The combination of a familiar phrase with an unfamiliar twist is intended to make you curious and want to read the rest of the article.

Comment: "Sweet" and "sweat" don't really sound alike - the vowel is different. But they're similar enough to make the wordplay work.